# ¿Como cambio el color del borde de una celda en PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

¿Como puedo cambiar el color del borde de una celda?

He probado esto:

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$color = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color('#4F80BD');
$sheet->getStyle('A2')->getBorders()->getTop()->setColor($color);
$sheet->getStyle('A2')->getBorders()->getTop()->setBorderStyle(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK);
```

pero el borde me aparece en negro, como si el color que creo no lo cogiese bien.

Gracias de antemano.

EDIT: Fallo mío, el color debia comenzar por "FF" y no por "#".

Gracias.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el orden en las 2 ultimas lineas. Estás asignando el color antes de establecer el borde

Comment: @Fergush así es como lo tenía inicialmente, pero lo había cambiado por probar.